# Parse.com JavaScript SDK - Not creating object on Safari

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

## The Problem

I am creating a simple form that uses Parse.com to store emails. Everything works fine on chrome however through Safari, it does not publish the object to Parse (never appears in the table). I am new to using Parse through JavaScript, might I be making an obvious mistake? Is this a limitation with Safari?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

### head

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Parse.initialize("##ID##", "##TOKEN##");
    console.log("Parse initialized");
</script>
```

### body

```
<form action="welcome.html" onsubmit="submitToParse();">

    <input type="email" id="email" onfocus="clearField(this,'Email');" class="field" name="email" value="Email">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Reserve Your Spot">

</form>

<script>
    function submitToParse() {
        var BetaUser = Parse.Object.extend("BetaUsers");
        console.log("Button pressed");
        var user = new BetaUser();
        var userEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;

        user.save({email: userEmail}).then(function(object) {
            console.log("success");
        }); 
    }
    function clearField(input,val) {
        if(input.value == val)
            input.value="";
        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue to be in the demo server not having a valid SSL certificate. In order for Parse to work it states it requires SSL certification which appeared to fix my problem. Still not sure why Chrome manages to work although that is a problem for another day.